# Sonata Admin Symfony2 with PHP-FPM Not Following Internal Redirects on Production

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm not sure if Sonata has something to do with this or if its related to PHP-FPM, but on production, when following app.php, internal redirects are not followed. If I visit /profile and the link is /profile/, I am taken to the page that asks me to click on /profile/. After a lot of Googling and reading the Book, I'm not sure where to turn.

Here is my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
  </FilesMatch>

  <Directory /var/www/mysite/web>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Inside web directory I have an .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've hit the website at mysite.com/profile and mysite.com/app.php/profile and still get the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symfony at all, but it seems like this is a routing issue of sorts. Is your `profile` route defined with the trailing slash? (Side note: I would expect an MVC framework to automatically handle these kinds of things. For example, Laravel trims out trailing slashes automatically.)

Comment: Laravel seems to use most of Symfony, so a lot of it is the same. The issue is not routing because typically it will follow the redirect on its own. It knows that /profile is supposed to redirect to /profile/, it just doesn't do it. The app_dev.php blocks redirects for debugging and such. The app.php controller is supposed to not do that.

Comment: That much I do know, but just not familiar with it from a *behavioural* point-of-view, if you know what I mean. I see your issue though, where `app.php` is the production index, which should follow the redirect automatically. I wonder if opening an issue with the Symfony team would help as this seems to be a bug, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We checked with Eugene and here is 2 possible solutions

So first let's check why it happens

It happens coz in sonata bundle we have event listener for redirect like that

```
 // display a validation page before redirecting, so the editor can edit the current page
    if ($page && $response->isRedirection() && $this->cmsSelector->isEditor() && !$request->get('_sonata_page_skip')) {
        $response = new Response($this->templating->render('SonataPageBundle:Page:redirect.html.twig', array(
            'response'   => $response,
            'page'       => $page,
        )));

        $response->setPrivate();

        $event->setResponse($response);

        return;
    }
```

and as you can get from this we can do one of two possible solutions

1. add get param `_sonata_page_skip=true`
2. overwrite in our bundle template for redirect and make `response|raw`

Comment: Additionally you can modify event handler. Just need to extends base listener class